# JSON schema for openapi3

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

What is a JSON schema reference for OpenAPI (https://www.openapis.org/) v3?

For example, if I want to define some schema as JSON I can do something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  // rest of the document will need to conform to the referenced schema
}
```

How can I reference OpenAPI 3 in the similar fashion?
I mean, can I write something like:

```
{
"$schema": "http://<some-url-for-openapi-v3>",
}
```

And this way enforce document to comply to schema and allow some advanced JSON editors to provide auto-completion during edit?

What would this *some-url-for-openapi-v3* be?

There are examples for v2 and v3 at:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/tree/master/examples
but v2 at the momemnt of writing has only yaml examples, and none of them (json or yaml) has anything like schema reference.

**Is it even possible to achieve?**

Answer (score 1):

1. In OpenApi you need to define paths, medthod, responces, components and schemas. More, you can even reference to schemas like this:

> ```
> paths:
>   /users:
>     post:           
>       parameters:
>         - in: path
>           name: users
>           required: true
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             example: users
>       responses:
>         200:
>           description: Success Response
>           content:
>             application/json; charset=utf-8:
>               schema:
>                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/SuccessResponce'
>
>
> Components:
>   schemas:
>     SuccessResponce:
>       description: 'Successful response'
>       type: string
> ```

2. Famous Swagger [Petstore example](https://petstore.swagger.io/) also answers your question.
3. Please walk through OpenApi specification [here](https://swagger.io/specification/).